# How do I enable an external display in Single User Mode via Terminal on a headless macbook?

Tags: terminal, macbook-pro, display, single-user, headless

I'm trying to troubleshoot video issues on macbook laptop with no display or a dead? display but can't see what I'm doing. I need a Terminal command to run 'blind' after I boot into Single User mode & enable an external monitor.
Hence-
How do I enable an external display in Single User Mode via Terminal on a headless macbook?

Comment: do you have second mac?